# Python projects are not supported on Windows Function App. Deploy to a Linux Function App

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, azure-functions

I followed the basic workflow to create a Python project and create a function from Http template. But this error is shown

[image]

I don't know why this message is shown. I have deploy many apps in azure function in couples of days. But this time I have to face this error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description in the screenshot you give, it seems you are trying to deploy python azure function to windows OS.

**This is impossible.**

Even you use some methods to upload your python function app to Windows OS function app on Azure, you function app will be unable to run because there is no environment.

The right way is to first create a function app based on Linux OS on Azure, then deploy your local function app to the function app on azure.

Comment: Thanks @Bowman. I already correct my mistake.

Comment: For future references, create the Cloud Function from Azure's portal. I was confused because VS Code doesn't give you the option in *advanced* to choose the OS.